# What will happen if an updated jgroups view message missed by a member?

Tags: java, jgroups

In our code, we have attached custom `org.jgroups.ReceiverAdapter` to the channel for the callback.

```
private JChannel channel = new JChannel(is)
channel.setReceiver(new JGroupsListener());

class JGroupsListener extends ReceiverAdapter {

        @Override
        public void viewAccepted(final View view) {
            viewChange(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void receive(final Message message) {
            processMessage(message);
        }

}
```

One of the members left the cluster, and the coordinator sent the new view to all existing members. But only a few members received the new view change notification and others did not receive it.

If the particular packet with the new view is missed by any member,

1. Will the coordinator resend the view again to that member?
2. If the coordinator resends the view then will that call invoke the ReceiverAdapter set in the channel?

jgroup version: 3.6.7.11.Final

Protocols used: TCP, MERGE3, FD_SOCK, FD, VERIFY_SUSPECT, NAKACK2, UNICAST3, GMS, FRAG2, RSVP

Answer (score 0):

Will the coordinator resend the view again to that member?

- Yes

If the coordinator resends the view then will that call invoke the
ReceiverAdapter set in the channel?

- Yes

ref: https://sourceforge.net/p/javagroups/discussion/18795/thread/d3705ccc4d/